# Adding more content to :before

Tags: html, css

I've used the following code to create a hover effect when users hover over an image:

```
&:before '
content: "example image"
Background: #444;
Padding: 20px
Height: 300px
Width: 300px
Font family: 'open sans'
Opacity: 0;
'
&:hover '
&:before '
Opacity: 1;
```

Basically I want to be a let to add text which I already have, plus a font awesome icon to appear when hover triggers.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing to keep in mind: **img tag doesn't handle pseudo elements** (except if the image is actually broken).

But, if you want to use an icon in addition to the text of your :before, you could apply it to the pseudo element **:after** of the same item. You can set it manually using the Unicode as content, and the FontAwesome for a font-family.

something like this (where *f2b9* is the Unicode of your fontawesome icon):

```css
div:after {
   content: "\f2b9";
   font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
}
```

Comment: Ok what do you mean by the image tag? I've put the image HTML between the a tag in my HTML is that ok?

Comment: yes. "a:before {}" will work, but "img:before" will not